# N++ Remove first 2 occurences of a doublequote in each line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove the first 2 double quotes of each line in a given file like this.

```
{
  "title": {
    "text": "Single Target Trinket Ratings",
    "style": {
  "fontFamily": "\"Lucida Grande\", \"Lucida Sans Unicode\", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
  "color": "#ffffff",
  "fontSize": "18px",
  "fontWeight": "normal",
  "fontStyle": "normal"
    }
```

So it ends up looking like this

```
 {
  title: {
    text: "Single Target Trinket Ratings",
    style: {
  fontFamily: "\"Lucida Grande\", \"Lucida Sans Unicode\", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
  color: "#ffffff",
  fontSize: "18px",
  fontWeight: "normal",
  fontStyle: "normal"
        }
```

I don't have a solid grasp so I have been manually going line by line with this

```
 ["{\[\]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^` to match the start of a line, then *capture* repeated spaces in a group, match `"`, capture non-`"` characters, then match `"` again. Then, replace with those two capture groups, thus removing the quotes:

```
^( *)"([^"]+)"
```

replace with

```
\1\2
```

https://regex101.com/r/RssEKu/1

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: @LordSkeletor The website mentionned by CertainPerformance (https://regex101.com) is an amazing website to learn about Regular Expression. I encourage you to have a look at it.